# How to replace ugly if constructs?

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot, clean-architecture

I have a method that receives a **CallbackQuery callbackQuery** based on the pressed built-in button.
Based on the received data, I want to call several methods
How can I do it right? The solution that I have at the moment is ugly, because if there are 10 or more buttons, this equals 10 conditionals. One of my solutions was a dictionary but I couldn't implement it due to calling multiple methods.
Excuse me for my english, my method would be at the bottom:

```
private static async Task BotOnCallbackQueryReceived(ITelegramBotClient botClient, CallbackQuery callbackQuery)
        {
            string url = $"https://api.telegram.org/bot{Configuration.BotToken}/sendMessage?chat_id={Configuration.idPrivateChannelProgrammers}&text={$"{Configuration.textMessageToSend} @{callbackQuery.From.Username}."}";
           
            if (callbackQuery.Data == "testString1")
            {
                SendsAMessageToUrlApiTelegramBot(url);
                _ = SendsAMessageToTheUserAsync(botClient, callbackQuery);
            }

            if (callbackQuery.Data == "testString2")
            {
                //string url = $"https://api.telegram.org/bot{Configuration.BotToken}/sendMessage?chat_id={Configuration.idPrivateChannelItManager}&text={$"{Configuration.textMessageToSend} @{callbackQuery.From.Username}."}";
                SendsAMessageToUrlApiTelegramBot(url);
                _ = SendsAMessageToTheUserAsync(botClient, callbackQuery);
            }

            if (callbackQuery.Data == "HelpUser")
            {
                const string messageCallb = "testString3";


                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                chatId: callbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, 
                text: $"{messageCallb}");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Employ Strategy pattern: https://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-how-to-use-strings-in-switch-statement/), you can use a string as distinction argument in a switch statement:

```
string str = "one";
          
// passing string "str" in 
// switch statement
switch (str) {              
    case "one":
        Console.WriteLine("It is 1");
        break;
  
    case "two":
        Console.WriteLine("It is 2");
        break;
  
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Nothing");
        break;
}
```

Comment: I heard the opinion that the use of switch constructions is undesirable, are there any other solutions? I myself thought about switch, is it much better than if?

Comment: Who ever told you switch is undesirable should be ignored or is woefully taken out of context. Solve the problem first before wondering if it's the latest fashion or against someone's opinion , or has a performance problem. Note it can be one if the most performant operations done in certain situations in certain languages

Comment: I will be more practical, thanks to everyone for the advice that you write to me.

Comment: @ItachiU - There are cases where switch case is undesirable, such as when you want to create a design where you want to be able to add cases without going back into finished classes and change the case logic to implement additional functionality ([Open-Closed Principle](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/open-close-principle/)). But there are also cases where it makes perfect sense to use switch case because the options are unlikely to change over time or if you are optimizing for performance. That said, it is not easy to tell by your question which scenario you have.